# how to add list for function and add function to ListView.builder in flutter

Tags: android, list, flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I thinking about how I can add list to function then add by ListView.builder , I trying 7 often but app give me error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GjXj.png) I'm dont know how but I search for this topic I'm read document [enter link description here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) I'm try this way in this document and try change some line in this document

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorsPage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorsPage2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ColorsPage2> createState() => _ColorsPage2State();
}

class _ColorsPage2State extends State<ColorsPage2> {
  final List<String> entries = <String>[
    'Red',
    'Pink',
    'Purple',
    'DeepPurple',
    'Indigo',
    'Blue',
    'LightBlue',
    'Cyan',
    'Teal',
    'Green',
    'LightGreen',
    'Lime',
    'Yellow',
    'Amber',
    'Orange',
    'DeepOrange',
    'Brown',
    'Grey',
    'BlueGrey',
  ];
  List<MaterialColor> colorCodes = <MaterialColor>[
    Colors.red,
    Colors.pink,
    Colors.purple,
    Colors.deepPurple,
    Colors.indigo,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.lightBlue,
    Colors.cyan,
    Colors.teal,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.lightGreen,
    Colors.lime,
    Colors.yellow,
    Colors.orange,
    Colors.deepOrange,
    Colors.brown,
    Colors.grey,
    Colors.blueGrey,
  ];

  Widget cardColor({MaterialColor? color, String? title, String? hexColor}) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Card(
        color: colorCodes[colorCodes.length],
        child: ListTile(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          title: Text(entries[entries.length]),
          subtitle: SelectableText(
              'This Is ${entries.length} Color , Hex: #$hexColor'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: entries.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return cardColor(
            color: colorCodes[colorCodes.length],
            title: entries[entries.length],
            hexColor: 'F44336FF',
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the index, you are using the length instead;

try this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: entries.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return cardColor(
            color: colorCodes[index],
            title: entries[index],
            hexColor: 'F44336FF',
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: No that colorCodes[index] will crash because colorCodes.length!= entries.length.

Comment: You are correct, but either ways it does not make sense to use length in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
color: colorCodes[colorCodes.length],
title: entries[entries.length],
```

The length property give you the size of a list starting from 1.
You try to access colorCodes[colorCodes.length] and will not work because a list start from 0 so you need to do colorCodes[colorCodes.length - 1]  for example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the length of data in your entries list is equal to the colorCodes.

As of now, you only have 18 data on colorCodes and 19 data on entries. After making sure both have the same length, try this:

```
Widget cardColor({MaterialColor? color, String? title, String? hexColor}) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Card(
        color: color,
        child: ListTile(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          title: Text(title),
          subtitle: SelectableText(
              'This Is $title Color , Hex: #$hexColor'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: entries.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return cardColor(
            color: colorCodes[index],
            title: entries[index],
            hexColor: 'F44336FF',
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```